# Disable foreground service notification using adb

Tags: android, adb

I have an app that has a foreground service that shows a notification. I want to hide that notification using adb.

I can disable the notification from the UI by going to "Settings"->"Apps"->{App of interest}->"Notifications" and turn off the notification under categories. I am looking for the equivalent behavior using adb.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?